# WindowsPhone : RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType : CannotResolve SymbolAncestorType

Tags: xaml, binding, windows-phone

I'm templating a listbox. I like to show a path only if the item is selected.

The DataTemplate :

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="itplPlayerOfTheDay">
    <Grid>
        ...
        <Grid Width="50" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,5,5,0">
            <Path Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor , AncestorType={ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"  Data="M32.5569,7.54591 C32.3883,13.1553 31.3485,16.9274z" Stretch="Uniform" Stroke="Black" >
            </Path>
        </Grid>
        ...
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Apparantly there is something wrong with my XAML. In the designer is states :  Cannot resolve symbol ancestor type.

Comment: Please don't put code in the title...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AncestorType is not supported on Windows Phone.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="itplPlayerOfTheDay">
    <Grid>
        ...
        <Grid Width="50" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,5,5,0">
            <Path Visibility="{Binding ElementName=yourListBoxName, Path=SelectedItem, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"  Data="M32.5569,7.54591 C32.3883,13.1553 31.3485,16.9274z" Stretch="Uniform" Stroke="Black" >
            </Path>
        </Grid>
        ...
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Make some changes in your BooleanToVisibilityConverter and done!

Comment: I added an extra property in MyView to take care of the Visible/Not Visible state