# Modify Grid of a UserControl in MainPage.xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, user-controls

I found many threads about this topic but couldn't make my app working, so I ask a new question here.

I want to make a UserControl-element that has a Grid that can be filled from outside.
this is the UserControl-Xaml-Part:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

     <Grid Grid.Column="2" x:Name="ButtonGrid"/>
</Grid>
```

Outside in my MainPage.xaml I want to use it like this:

```
<UserControls:MyControl>
    <UserControls:MyControl.ButtonGrid>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="130"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="130"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="130"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="130"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            // Add elements and stuff
        </Grid>
    </UserControls:MyControl.ButtonGrid>
</UserControls:AppBar>
```

But I don't get this far. It says that "ButtonGrid" was not recognized or couldn't access Member (my translation from german error-message). But when I type `UserControls:MyControl.` it suggests `ButtonGrid`.

The MyControl.xaml.cs looks like this:

```
namespace myApp
{
    public partial class MyControl: UserControl
    {
        public Grid ButtonGrid { get; set; }

        // or
        public Grid ButtonGrid
        {
            get { return (Grid)GetValue(ButtonGridProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ButtonGridProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonGridProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonGrid", typeof(Grid), typeof(MyControl), new PropertyMetadata(new Grid()));

        public MyControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried many ways of making this "ButtonGrid"-value visible and working but still it doesn't. Any Ideas?

**EDIT** 
I can get the Grid in the codebehind with a simple getter. But its just not straight-forward to create stuff somewhere and THEN put them to the place I want them to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to John Bowen for the right idea. Now the best solution I've got so far is:
MainPage.xaml

```
<local:MyControlx:Name="Control" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                Height="98" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
    <local:MyControl.Content>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="130"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="130"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="130"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="130"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!-- Stuff inside that works! -->

        </Grid>
    </local:MyControl.Content>
</local:MyControl>
```

And MyControl.xaml (which is a ContentControl now!):

```
<Grid x:Name="MyCtrl" Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"
      Height="98" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
      Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ActualWidth}">
    <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform x:Name="moveTransform" />
    </Grid.RenderTransform>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="2"
                      Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=DataContext}"/>

    <!-- Buttons and stuff that should be always there in Grid.Column=0 and Grid.Column=4 -->

    </Button>
</Grid>
```

The buttons and stuff from MainPage.xaml are visible, clickable and nothing crashes. But I don't see the buttons or PhoneAccentBrush-background from the inside of MyControl.xaml =/
So this must be the right way I just miss something..

**Edit:**
If I make MyControl to a UserControl the `.Content` overwrites everything that was inside.
If I make it a ContentControl it seems to see the inner Grid because it places everything almost in the right place. But still I can't see any other elements that are declared inside the MyControl. If I don't set the `.Content` I see all internal stuff, all methods working but of course nothing that I wanted to place inside is there.

**Edit2:**
I've managed it somehow but stumbled into new errors. But I guess its better to link the other thread ;)
[Keep a reference to objects passed to a UserControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23077012/keep-a-reference-to-objects-passed-toa-usercontrol)

Answer (score 1):

Setting a Name on an element in XAML creates a private field for that object that you can then access in code-behind. It does not make it a placeholder for other content as you're trying to use it. If you want to inject external content into your XAML use a `ContentPresenter` or some `ContentControl` derivative and set the content you want to inject to its `Content` property. This is the pattern used in general for `ContentControls` so you can look at the default template for `Button` for example and see this pattern.

So to use this:

```
<local:MyControl>
  <local:MyControl.CustomContent>
    <Grid>
      <!-- elements and stuff to pass in -->
    </Grid>
  </local:MyControl.CustomContent>
</local:MyControl>
```

You would have a DependencyProperty in MyControl (CustomContent) like you tried already (but it should be type object unless you have a specific reason for some other type). Then your control's XAML would look more like:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    ...
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="2" Content="{Binding CustomContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:MyControl}}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
That's not exactly what I wanted. I want to use the UserControl as a "standard design" and define the inner "elements and stuff" in the normal .xaml. I'll try to inverse what you suggested and use the ContentPresenter from the UserControl.

Comment: Ok, I see I misunderstood.. Try to implement now. Will post again when it works or I gave up :D

Comment: Now I tried a bit. Sadly `AncestorType` is not supported in Windows Phone. ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233072/windowsphone-relativesource-mode-findancestor-ancestortype-cannotresolve-sy ). I am not sure about `FindAncestor` yet. Try to find a WP8-way