# (Windows Phone 8.1) Is it possible to get the Values of a Grandparent in a ListViewItem per Binding?

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I have a programmicly added ContentControl with a ListView. The DataSource of the ListView is set to a List of the ContentControl.

The first item of the ListView is a picture, the rest are the items from the List. I already have a Selector with the two templates. Problem is, the Value for the picture is located above the ScrollView in the ContenControl. Is it possible to bind that Value?

Something like this:

```
Text="{Binding Source=ContenControl, Path=mImage}"
```

Comment: You could try this `<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=slider1, Path=Value}"/>`

Comment: Probelm is, I can´t really use ElementName because I add like 60 of these ContentControls, and I can´t imagine how to get the Name of the specific one I need.

Comment: traversing based on type is not supported on wp8 http://stackoverflow.com/a/15248474/1876572

Comment: Can you provide whole xaml code from your page (control)?